# How to use va_list object in a nested way, especially on gcc x64 compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, glibc

Please look through my small C/C++ program.

```
// va_nest.c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void nest2(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args2, args_dig;
    int *pi, i;

    va_start(args2, fmt);

    args_dig = va_arg(args2, va_list); 
        // !!! try to fetch the nested va_list object.
    pi = va_arg(args_dig, int*);
    i = va_arg(args_dig, int);

    printf("Inner: @%p , %d\n", pi, i);

    va_end(args2);
}

void nest1(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args1;
    va_start(args1, fmt);

    nest2(fmt, args1);

    va_end(args1);
}

int main()
{
    int var = 11;
    printf("Outer: @%p , %d\n", &var, var);
    nest1("abc", &var, var);
    return 0;
}
```

On openSUSE 13.1 x86, it outputs just want I expect(no matter using gcc or g++),

```
Outer: @0xbfa18d8c , 11
Inner: @0xbfa18d8c , 11
```

However, it FAILS with x86_64 compiler on openSUSE 13.1 x64 machine.

If I compile it with `gcc`, it compiles ok, but output is unexpected.

```
$ gcc -o vac va_nest.c

$ ./vac
Outer: @0x7fffb20f766c , 11
Inner: @0x1b01000000636261 , 4209411
```

If I compile it with `g++`, it even fails to compile.

```
$ g++ -o vacpp va_nest.c
va_nest.c: In function ‘void nest2(const char*, ...)’:
va_nest.c:12:11: error: invalid array assignment
  args_dig = va_arg(args2, va_list);
           ^
```

gcc and g++ version is 4.8.1

Can anybody help me with that? I hope to achieve the same result on x64 as in Linux x86 compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize passing va_list object's address(instead of object itself) is feasible, verified on linux gcc and MSVC 2008(32-bit & 64-bit compiler).

```
// va_nesta.c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void nest2(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args2, *args_dig;
    int *pi, i;

    va_start(args2, fmt);

    args_dig = va_arg(args2, va_list*); 
        // !!! ★ try to fetch the nested va_list object's address.
    pi = va_arg(*args_dig, int*);
    i = va_arg(*args_dig, int);

    printf("Inner: @%p , %d\n", pi, i);

    va_end(args2);
}

void nest1(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args1;
    va_start(args1, fmt);

    nest2(fmt, &args1); // ★use va_list object's address!

    va_end(args1);
}

int main()
{
    int var = 11;
    printf("Outer: @%p , %d\n", &var, var);
    nest1("abc", &var, var);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to be clever with `va_list`. Instead, use code like this:

```
nest2(fmt, args1);
```

(i.e. make sure that all functions use the same structure hidden behind `va_list`). Then you can define the second function like so:

```
void nest2(const char *fmt, va_list args1)
```

Also make sure that you call `va_end()` **exactly once**. Nesting won't work reliably (i.e. if it works, that's more luck than anything else).

If in doubt, look at the source code of GLIBC, especially [fprintf.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/fprintf.c) and [vfprintf.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c).

```
int
__fprintf (FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  int done;

  va_start (arg, format);
  done = vfprintf (stream, format, arg);
  va_end (arg);

  return done;
}
```

and later:

```
int
vfprintf (FILE *s, const CHAR_T *format, va_list ap)
{
```